# How to make a google spreadsheet into a list or a well spaced string?

Tags: python, list, google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to extract the data on a spreadsheet either into a nested 2-d list or copy and paste somehow as a string in which the spacing without format is not terrible. At first, I was thinking of just stripping the duplicate spaces away, but sometimes certain cells end up having not a single space between them and that's why I cannot do that. Anyway, I need to be able to extract long data which is why I need an easy way of accessing without having to go an fix the spacing for all the names and their corresponding information.

Comment: Could you add some examples of the type of data you are trying to produce? That way we can have a better understanding of the question and give you a better solution

Comment: First name, Last name, ID

Comment: Hey @StevenEvenU were you able to solve your issue with my answer? Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it in case it was useful to you. Otherwise, kindly describe the issue you are having,  so we may help you. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python), you could use the following code:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        for row in values:
            print(', '.join(row))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You will need to set the `SPREADSHEET_ID` to your Spreadsheet's Id and the `RANGE_NAME` to the range you are attempting to fetch.

Afterwards, the data retrieved will be in the `values` variable, as a 2D Array. You can also use the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module for printing the data in a more human-readable way.

You can read more about this solution in the [Python Quickstart page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python).